# Dynamic List Checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, list

My code can be found here in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X23LG/)

I have an issue regarding the dynamic checkbox selection in a list.
If i check `parent1 checkbox`, the children of the `parent 1` should only be checked.

Like if i check `Parent1, Category 1.1, Category 1.2, Category 1.3` Should only be checked,
And if i uncheck `Parent 1, the childrens` are also be unchecked.

As these values are coming from the database in a foreach loop, Which i have quoted below in my code.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="middle-right">
        <ul class="mid-right-list">
            <?php   
                foreach($pntrs AS $ps)
                {
                $catrs=$media->Catgselectn($ps['parent_id'],'sales_catmgmt');
            ?>

            <li><b>+ <?php echo $ps['parent_name'];?></b>

            <?php
                foreach($catrs AS $cg)
                {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="catg[]" value="<?php echo $cg['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $cg['cat_name']; ?></li>
            </ul>
            <? } ?>
              </li> 
             <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding separate id/classes to ul, so u can change checkbox state with jQuery?

Comment: Write a trigger on parent check box, then ever parent checkbox is checked then you can check all those child which lies under that parent.

Comment: Hi Suleman. I have tried it. But facing few issues with the coding. Is it possible for you to provide the code.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding an onchange attribute for each input and in that function set the children as checked

Comment: Hi Justinas Jurciukonis.. No can u plz suggest me how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any problem to use jquery? this can be done easily with jQuery.

Comment: Hi MonirulNo i dont will you please suggest me how it can be done

Comment: I have added the solution as answer with your code. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Jquery Solution. You can use jquery. [`JsFriddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/X23LG/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul')
            .find("input[type='checkbox']")
            .prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you think its helpful then you can mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way - you can write a jquery trigger for parent ids, that contain the different attribues. Then which parent checkbox is checked, find that id then mark those child checkboxes accordingly.

example of trigger:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').delegate('.parent_class_of_checkbox', 'click', function(evt) {
        // here mark checked to child checkbox.
    });
});
```